# Out of Scope Supervisory Duties

Tags: professionalism

I started my job a while ago like what I do. During my interview I was told I was going to help other people who do indirect work for our department. Recently my boss told me I am to be aware of everything these people do for us. My boss is still their supervisor on paper but whenever there is an issue, I am asked by my boss about their work and made accountable for their mistakes. I help them out and guide them but do not act as their supervisor, because I am not. How can I approach my boss about this situation? I am not their supervisor but would not mind doing it for a raise.

Comment: Have you given the supervisor from these other departments feedback on the poor performance? You may not be the supervisor, but you should keep people informed.

Comment: Yes, these people have a supervisor and this supervisor is included in the group of people I "help out". Whenever there are any mistakes or even good performance I adress it with their direct supervisor or with them but always include the supervisor in the conversation.

Answer (score 10):

Let me try to understand this... your role is to advise and mentor but you are held accountable for their mistakes?

Think about that, you are charged with responsibility in merely an advisory role in which you have no direct power.

More money isn't the issue here, I would refuse to be put in this situation without having some teeth. You shouldn't accept this either. You are being made to be a [Fall-Guy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_guy).

> a person who is used as a scapegoat; someone who ends up taking the blame (or being held responsible) for the actions of another person or group. Someone placed in the position of fall guy is often referred to as someone who is "taking the fall."

The best thing for yourself is to very professionally and formally request of your boss to be given direct control over the technical management of this team for the given project, including the ability to override technical decisions, approve various technical designs and work, and the ability to be a technical lead in all things.

If this request is denied or ignored them request to be removed from this responsibility.

Comment: +1. *Responsibility without authority* is a very dangerous position to be in.

Comment: It is possible the boss is giving the OP this responsibility to see how s/he handles managing them, before making her/him their manager. It all depends on the approach, and her/his trust in the boss. It may be a delicate situation (fall guy setup), or it might not be. Depends on how well the OP and boss communicate.

Comment: @JenniferS, in my experience it never works out well to have responsibility without authority even as a test. It isn't a fair test either. If you are to have responsibilty for someone else's work, you must have the corresponding authority to tell them to fix something when it is wrong.

Comment: My boss and I have good communication. They trust me more than I trust them. In this situation I feel as though this is just pushing more of their responsibilities on me. I don't mind the extra work at all but I would like the title/authority to go with it and obviously a monetary compensation would not hurt.

Answer (score 6):

Clearly your boss has expectations that you don't understand (or perhaps you just don't agree with them).

Talk to you boss. Ask for understanding. Try something like "I'd like to make sure I do my job well. I'm trying to understand your expectations in regard to these other people." That will likely go over well with your boss.

But don't go in with the attitude that "I won't mind doing it, but only if you give me a raise." That's a good way to lose your job.

Unless you have some sort of very detailed contract (or unless you live in a part of the world where job details are handled very differently than in my part of the world), your boss determines the specifics of your role. The fact that it isn't exactly what you thought you understood during the interview, doesn't mean that you have a right to refuse and/or demand a raise.

Comment: Of course. I would not go into "this isn't part of my job duties" attitude. I would actually like to supervise them, but what if my boss says this is just "other duties as assigned"? It seems like reading 7 people's emails is more than just helping out which is what we discussed just recently as my role with them.

Comment: The OP may have more authority than he/she thinks.

Comment: Sorry, I realize I was not clear in my question. I do think I have authority but my boss never sat down with me to explain that I would be a supervisor and didn't tell these people either. I just don't know if I should just ask to be the supervisor and call it a day or if I should ask to be supervisor and also ask for title and raise. I don't want to be looked as uncooperative but this will take a good amount of time to deal with.